# Can I use TSA PreCheck with a non-participating airline?

Tags: air-travel, tsa-precheck, trusted-traveler

Can I use our Known Traveler Number for TSA PreCheck if the airline we are flying doesn't recognize them in their system?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot.  TSA PreCheck requires the participation of the airline.  If your airline doesn't participate, you can't use it.

https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/faq

> Why can’t I use the TSA Pre✓® lanes when traveling on any airline?
>
> Passengers must be traveling on an airline that has entered into a partnership with TSA. Under this partnership, TSA works with the airline to establish system and checkpoint requirements and determine operation of TSA Pre✓® lanes at airports.

You can find a list of participating airlines at https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/map.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the airlines that participate in [TSA Pre-check](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/participating-airlines):

> - Aeromexico
> - Air Canada
> - Alaska Airlines
> - Allegiant Air
> - American Airlines
> - Aruba Airlines
> - Avianca
> - Boutique Airlines
> - Cape Air
> - Delta Air Lines
> - Emirates
> - Etihad Airways
> - Frontier Airlines
> - Hawaiian Airlines
> - JetBlue Airways
> - Key Lime Air
> - Lufthansa
> - Miami Air International
> - OneJet
> - Seaborne Airlines
> - Southern Airways Express
> - Southwest Airlines
> - Spirit Airlines
> - Sun Country Airlines
> - Sunwing Airlines
> - United Airlines
> - Virgin America
> - Virgin Atlantic
> - WestJet
> - Xtra Airways

If your airline is not listed, then you won't be able to enter the TSA Pre-check lane at the airport. An easy way to check, is to look at your boarding pass, and if you see TSA Precheck listed, then you may use the TSA Pre-check lane. If you have a Known Travelers Number (KTN), you can also call your airline to add it to your reservation.